# HTML table to display Firebase Realtime Database data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firebase

So i have been using this codes to get the data from my firebase realtime database, it works. But the only problem i get is the code does not refresh itself.

This is the image of before add or deleting data from database

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGaoL.jpg

This is the image after add or delete data from database

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDSQX.jpg

The latest data is circled in red.

How do i make it refresh the whole code? I just want to get new "child_added"

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="svclist">
     <tr>
<th>Full Name</th>
<th>Car Model</th>
<th>Car Number</th>
 <th>Service Center</th>
<th>Service Type</th>
<th>Service Date</th>
<th>Service Time</th>
<th>Remarks</th>
<th>Person In Charge</th>
<th>Action</th>
</tr>
 </table>

   <script>
    var database = firebase.database();

   database.ref().child("Service Schedule").on('value', function (snapshot) 
       {
          if (snapshot.exists()) {
            var content = '';
            snapshot.forEach(function (data) {
            var val = data.val();
               content += '<tr>';
              content += '<td>' + val.Name + '</td>';
              content += '<td>' + val.CarModel + '</td>';
              content += '<td>' + val.CarNumber + '</td>';
              content += '<td>' + val.ServiceCenter + '</td>';
              content += '<td>' + val.ServiceType + '</td>';
              content += '<td>' + val.ServiceDate + '</td>';
              content += '<td>' + val.ServiceTime + '</td>';
               content += '<td>' + val.Remarks + '</td>';
                  });
               $('#svclist').append(content);
                  }
                })</script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by _does not refresh_. Can you elaborate? Because at the same time you said it works, and in the screenshots I see that the data is correctly added.

Comment: Dear molamk, what i meant was, by referring to the second picture, i want only the data in the red circle, and not the data outside of the red circle whenever i add or delete data. i just want the latest appended data. 

Let me put this in another way, 
whenever i add or delete any data, it will show the whole data again including those that i've added previously, so by referring to the second picture, i would like to have the data only show the latest database, which i just delete or add any data, without showing duplicate data. I dont know if i explain it clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand you want the table to reflect events that happen *after* you load the page. That way you can discard previous data points.

A simple way to do this, is to add a `timestamp` property to your *data*. So when retrieving your items, you can filter all those who were created before the `timestamp`. It looks like this

```
ref.orderByChild('timestamp').startAt(Date.now()).on('child_added', 
function(snapshot) {
  console.log('new record', snap.key());
});
```

As for deleting an item, you can use the `child_removed` event. Here is an example from [Firebase's docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#listen_for_child_events)

```
commentsRef.on('child_removed', function(data) {
  deleteComment(postElement, data.key);
});
```